# Combine Date and Time columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

```py
data = {'Date': ['01-06-2013', '02-06-2013', '02-06-2013', '02-06-2013', '02-06-2013', '03-06-2013', '03-06-2013', '03-06-2013', '03-06-2013', '04-06-2013'],
        'Time': ['23:00:00', '01:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00', '01:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00', '01:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         Date      Time
0  01-06-2013  23:00:00
1  02-06-2013  01:00:00
2  02-06-2013  21:00:00
3  02-06-2013  22:00:00
4  02-06-2013  23:00:00
5  03-06-2013  01:00:00
6  03-06-2013  21:00:00
7  03-06-2013  22:00:00
8  03-06-2013  23:00:00
9  04-06-2013  01:00:00
```

How do I combine data['Date'] & data['Time']  to get the following? Is there a way of doing it using `pd.to_datetime`?

```
Date
01-06-2013 23:00:00
02-06-2013 01:00:00
02-06-2013 21:00:00
02-06-2013 22:00:00
02-06-2013 23:00:00
03-06-2013 01:00:00
03-06-2013 21:00:00
03-06-2013 22:00:00
03-06-2013 23:00:00
04-06-2013 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 294, accepted):

It's worth mentioning that you may have been able to read this in **directly** e.g. if you were using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) using `parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']]`.

Assuming these are just strings you could simply add them together (with a space), allowing you to use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), which works without specifying the `format=` parameter

```
In [11]: df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
Out[11]:
0    01-06-2013 23:00:00
1    02-06-2013 01:00:00
2    02-06-2013 21:00:00
3    02-06-2013 22:00:00
4    02-06-2013 23:00:00
5    03-06-2013 01:00:00
6    03-06-2013 21:00:00
7    03-06-2013 22:00:00
8    03-06-2013 23:00:00
9    04-06-2013 01:00:00
dtype: object

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
Out[12]:
0   2013-01-06 23:00:00
1   2013-02-06 01:00:00
2   2013-02-06 21:00:00
3   2013-02-06 22:00:00
4   2013-02-06 23:00:00
5   2013-03-06 01:00:00
6   2013-03-06 21:00:00
7   2013-03-06 22:00:00
8   2013-03-06 23:00:00
9   2013-04-06 01:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Alternatively, without the `+ ' '`, but the `format=` parameter must be used. Additionally, pandas is good at inferring the format to be converted to a `datetime`, however, specifying the exact format is faster.

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%m-%d-%Y%H:%M:%S')
```

*Note: surprisingly (for me), this works fine with NaNs being converted to NaT, but it is worth worrying that the conversion (perhaps using the `raise` argument).*

### `%%timeit`

```py
# sample dataframe with 10000000 rows using df from the OP
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(1000000)]).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
[result]:
1.73 s ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%m-%d-%Y%H:%M:%S')
[result]:
1.33 s ± 9.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 63):

The accepted answer works for columns that are of datatype `string`. For completeness: I come across this question when searching how to do this when the columns are of datatypes: date and time.

```
df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['date_column_name'],r['time_column_name']),1)
```

Comment: I cannot find anything regarding the `time` dtype, in pandas. I have rather a `timedelta` (and a `datetime`) in which case you just need to add them, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352414/1060349)

Comment: When I 'pd.read_excel' an Excel column that Excel identifies as "Time," pandas also reads it as "Time" automatically without any parsing argument required. Thanks for this solution. +1

Comment: Just a note, as of pandas 1.0.0 `pd.datetime` [has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#deprecations) and it's suggested to just explicitly import the `datetime` module instead.

Comment: This method is too slow for big datasets. It's faster to convert both columns to strings, join them and use `to_datetime`.

Answer (score 38):

Cast the columns if the types are different (`datetime` and `timestamp` or `str`) and use `to_datetime` :

```
df.loc[:,'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.astype(str)+' '+df.Time.astype(str))
```

Result :

```
0   2013-01-06 23:00:00
1   2013-02-06 01:00:00
2   2013-02-06 21:00:00
3   2013-02-06 22:00:00
4   2013-02-06 23:00:00
5   2013-03-06 01:00:00
6   2013-03-06 21:00:00
7   2013-03-06 22:00:00
8   2013-03-06 23:00:00
9   2013-04-06 01:00:00
```

Best,

Comment: This was the only option I could get to work with Python `datetime` module types. But now I have this one report converted to `datetime64[ns]`, and this leaves me with mixed types elsewhere, which is never a good thing.

Comment: This option is inefficient compared to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978188/7758804) because the two columns are already strings. Therefore, using `.astype(str)` is unnecessary (given the OP). Also, `df['Date'] = ` will suffice; no need for `.loc` (e.g. `df.loc[:,'Date'] =`)

Answer (score 22):

You can use this to merge date and time into the same column of dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd    
data_file = 'data.csv' #path of your file
```

Reading .csv file with merged columns Date_Time:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

You can use this line to keep both other columns also.

```
data.set_index(['Date', 'Time'], drop=False)
```

Comment: You can also use custom `date_parser`, for example `parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 16):

You can also convert to `datetime` without string concatenation, by combining [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), which create `datetime` and `timedeltea` objects, respectively. Combined with [`pd.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), you can remove the source Series simultaneously:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Time'))

print(df)

             DateTime
0 2013-01-06 23:00:00
1 2013-02-06 01:00:00
2 2013-02-06 21:00:00
3 2013-02-06 22:00:00
4 2013-02-06 23:00:00
5 2013-03-06 01:00:00
6 2013-03-06 21:00:00
7 2013-03-06 22:00:00
8 2013-03-06 23:00:00
9 2013-04-06 01:00:00

print(df.dtypes)

DateTime    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Great general solution! I had type datetime date and type str time and this worked.

Comment: Actually this is much faster than the accepted answer, especially if the date column is already of type `pd.Timestamp`.

Comment: does this work reliably with daylight saving time?

Answer (score 12):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [jka.ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3333687/jka-ne) so:

I had to amend [jka.ne's line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474812/2802352) for it to work:

```
df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['date_column_name'],r['time_column_name']).time(),1)
```

This might help others.

Also, I have tested a different approach, using `replace` instead of `combine`:

```
def combine_date_time(df, datecol, timecol):
    return df.apply(lambda row: row[datecol].replace(
                                hour=row[timecol].hour,
                                minute=row[timecol].minute),
                    axis=1)
```

which in the OP's case would be:

```
combine_date_time(df, 'Date', 'Time')
```

I have timed both approaches for a relatively large dataset (>500.000 rows), and they both have similar runtimes, but using `combine` is faster (59s for `replace` vs 50s for `combine`).

Answer (score 12):

First make sure to have the right data types:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"])
```

Then you easily combine them:

```
df["DateTime"] = df["Date"] + df["Time"]
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer **really depends on what your column types are**. In my case, I had `datetime` and `timedelta`.

```
> df[['Date','Time']].dtypes
Date     datetime64[ns]
Time    timedelta64[ns]
```

If this is your case, then you just need to add the columns:

```
> df['Date'] + df['Time']
```

Comment: The accepted answer assumes strings: *"Assuming these are just strings you could simply add them together (with a space)"*. My answers are for `datetime` and `timedelta`. The main answer somehow figure out that the columns were strings, or maybe it was just the answer that worked for the one that posted the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use the  `combine` function:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner, to do it. You simply concatenate the two string in each of the column with a " " space in between.

Say df is your dataframe and columns are 'Time' and 'Date'. And your new column is DateAndTime.

```
df['DateAndTime'] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['Time'],sep=" ")
```

And if you also wanna handle entries like datetime objects, you can do this. You can tweak the formatting as per your needs.

```
df['DateAndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateAndTime'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

***Cheers!! Happy Data Crunching.***

Answer (score 2):

My dataset had 1second resolution data for a few days and parsing by the suggested methods here was very slow. Instead I used:

```py
dates = pandas.to_datetime(df.Date, cache=True)
times = pandas.to_timedelta(df.Time)
datetimes  = dates + times
```

Note the use of `cache=True` makes parsing the dates very efficient since there are only a couple unique dates in my files, which is not true for a combined date and time column.

Comment: does this work reliably with daylight saving time?

Comment: No, it probably doesn't. Then again, the input data as shown in the original question doesn't give enough information to identify a specific time in the event of a daylight saving change (e.g., when is "2024-11-03 1:30"? There are two such times in US Eastern timezone.)

Comment: Testing it out some more, if `Date` and `Time` give the naive wall-clock time in a timezone, say `America/Chicago`, then doing my suggestion followed by `datetimes.dt.tz_localize('America/Chicago')` appears to give the correct answer except in the case of ambiguous times, which can be handled by the `ambiguous` argument to `tz_localize` depending on the situation (e.g., `ambiguous='infer'` if your timepoints are ordered). But test this yourself, I might have missed some edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

DATA:

<TICKER>,<PER>,**<DATE>,<TIME>**,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>
SPFB.RTS,1,**20190103,100100**,106580.0000000,107260.0000000,106570.0000000,107230.0000000,3726

CODE:

```
data.columns = ['ticker', 'per', 'date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']    
data.datetime = pd.to_datetime(data.date.astype(str) + ' ' + data.time.astype(str), format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution is to parse dates within `read_csv` (or other read_ functions) directly. It is not obvious how to manage two columns in date_parser but here it is:

```py
date_parser = lambda x,y: datetime.strptime(f"{x}T{y}", "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S")
date = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates={'date': ['Date', 'Time']}, date_parser=date_parser)
```