# Unknown column appearing using pandas to import sqlite3 database

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sqlite

I'm using a temperature and humidity sensor connected to a Raspberry Pi to log those in regular intervals into a sqlite3 DB with the following schema:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (tdate DATE, ttime TIME, temperature NUMERIC, humidity NUMERIC);
```

For test purposes there are just two entries:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sensor_data;
2017-03-02|19:04:42|19.8999996185303|51.5
2017-03-02|19:26:08|19.8999996185303|51.2000007629395
```

Now I'd like to analyze and plot the data using pandas:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

    with conn:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM sensor_data", conn,
                        parse_dates={'tdate':"%Y-%m-%d",'ttime':"%H:%M:%S"})
        print(df)

conn.close()
```

The result:

```
$ ./test.py 
   tdate               ttime  temperature   humidity
0 2017-03-02 1900-01-01 19:04:42         19.9  51.500000
1 2017-03-02 1900-01-01 19:26:08         19.9  51.200001
```

My question is:
How do I get rid of the column containing the `1900-01-01`'s and then combine `tdate` and `ttime` into one column?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Lars

Comment: is `1900-01-01` its own column or is a part of another column's value?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas) might also come in handy when wanting to combine those dates

Comment: It looks like it is part of df['ttime'], maybe my formatting string is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [13]: df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM sensor_data", conn,
    ...:                        parse_dates=['tdate','ttime']).drop('tdate', 1)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                ttime  temperature  humidity
0 2017-03-02 19:04:42         19.9      51.5
1 2017-03-02 19:26:08         19.9      51.2
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxU, your answer is doing just what I was looking for! Much appreciated!