# Improve performance filtering on object column with dates

Tags: python, performance, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Working on the NYC car crash dataset. The current csv has data from 2012 and I wanted to extract out the 2017 values. Thing is DATE is an object dtype and trying something like this ended up taking too long

```
data = data[(pd.to_datetime((data['DATE'])).dt.year == 2017)]
```

Here is how a sample of the data looks

[image: Head of the dataset]

Does anyone possibly know of a faster or more efficient way? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck is almost certainly in `datetime` conversion.

To improve performance, you can utilise the `infer_datetime_format` argument of `pd.to_datetime`. As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> **infer_datetime_format** : boolean, default False
>
> If True and no format is given, attempt to infer the format of the
>   datetime strings, and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method
>   of parsing them. In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by
>   ~5-10x.

For example:

```
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
data = data[data['DATE'].dt.year == 2017)]
```

---

Alternatively, you can specify the [precise format](http://strftime.org/):

```
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
data = data[data['DATE'].dt.year == 2017)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much jpp I didnt know about infer_datetime_format that really did help and speed things up.

Comment: @laughingllama42, or just specify the date format explicitly when calling `pd.to_datetime(data.DATE,  format='%m/%d/%Y')`. It took 3 seconds to convert with the format specified, but 144 seconds without it specified.

Comment: @ALollz, Thanks - also added a link to the `datetime` abbreviation page.

Comment: @jpp is there any way to modify this to also add in the time column?

Comment: @laughingllama42, Yes. There are many different formats you can incorporate, [this link](http://strftime.org/) is a complete guide. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas) for how to combine 2 columns.