# Pandas, merge Date and Time column from read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this .csv file:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Up","Down"
03/20/2018,17:01,2723.25,2724.50,2723.25,2723.75,372,345
03/20/2018,17:02,2723.75,2724.25,2723.50,2724.00,127,49
03/20/2018,17:03,2724.00,2724.00,2723.75,2723.75,55,11
03/20/2018,17:04,2724.00,2724.50,2724.00,2724.00,105,25
```

That I can import in Pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/file.TXT", parse_dates=['Date', 'Time'], sep=",")
```

I would now like to add a `Datetime` column to merge the `Date` and `Time` columns.

Can this be done at import? If not, how can I do this without having to iterate over every line?

In pseudocode, I would need something like this:

```
df['Datetime'] = # datetime(date=df['Date'], time=df['Time'])
```

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920602)

Comment: Thanks! I've missed that...