# Adding pandas columns with date and time variables

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, concatenation

I have this column in a pandas dataframe:

```
 dataset['Start Pump Time']:
 0        10:50
 1        14:25
 2        03:00
 3        21:15
 4        02:05
 Name: Start Pump Time, Length: 94052, dtype: object`
```

and this
one

```
dataset['Start Pump Date']
0       2018-12-12
1       2018-12-16
2       2019-01-14
3       2019-05-06
4       2019-06-28
Name: Start Pump Date, Length: 94052, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want merge those two columns and create a column that has both the date and the time and delete the previous two colums.
I have tried with pandas.to_datetime but my inexperience hasn't helped in finding the correct solution till now.
Thanks

Comment: did you try options described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas)?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Start Pump Date'] + ' ' + df['Start Pump Time'])
```

check here [Combine Date and Time columns using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas)

Comment: this won't work I guess since `df['Start Pump Date']` is not of type string but datetime

Comment: I have seen the aforementioned thread, and what I get with your command is :
`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'`
Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the other column to `timedelta` and add:

```
pd.to_timedelta(dataset['Start Pump Time'] + ":00") +  dataset['Start Pump Date']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but what I get is this:

`ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format`