# Convert time and date columns to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have two columns - date and time.

```
date                  | time    
2012-10-16 00:00:00   | 09:38:08-05:00
```

I wish to combine these two and form a timestamp. I don't know how to approach the problem. Should I strip the date, add time, and create a DateTime and then convert to timestamp.

Comment: is this in a pandas dataframe? what is the data type of these columns ?

Comment: @MrFuppes It is pandas dataframe and datatype is Object. I have read these from an excel file.

Comment: ok I've added an answer, which covers some conversions (datetime -> string, see comments in code), you might not need them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is a variation of [Combine Date and Time columns using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17978092/10197418) but you have a UTC offset, so let's parse this correctly as well. Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2012-10-16 00:00:00'],
                   'time': ['09:38:08-05:00']})

# make sure date column is date as string dtype
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date.astype(str)

# make sure time column is of string dtype
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str)

# combine date and time column (now both string dtype), then parse to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

# df['datetime']
# 0   2012-10-16 09:38:08-05:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
```

***optional: specify a time zone.*** UTC-5 is a fixed offset, which is sometimes not desired. If you know the tz of your source, you can simply add that info:

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert('US/Central')

# df['datetime']
# 0   2012-10-16 09:38:08-05:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Central]
```

***optional: parse to UTC directly.*** In most cases, it is best to work with UTC. You can parse to UTC directly:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'], utc=True)

# df['datetime']
# 0   2012-10-16 14:38:08+00:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```