# Plotting daily mean spreaded over months from a time series

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have been trying to achieve a plot for hours and seem to be going in the wrong direction but can't figure out what's wrong.

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/asauve/cdc-us-births-data-19692008

I would like to find out the "mean daily births by date" grouped by months.

and here is what I am doing.

First I calculate the daily mean:

```
dailyMean = dataFrame.groupby(['year','month','day'])['births'].mean().reset_index()
```

[image]

Then I am plotting the result

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.plot(dailyMean.iloc[:,1],dailyMean.iloc[:,3])
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
              ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
plt.ylabel("mean births")
plt.xlabel("months")
plt.show()
```

This is what I got

[image]

I also tried seaborn lineplot and this is what I got.

[image]

But I am expecting something like expected plot
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It may be useful to use [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas)

Comment: Actually, I tried that too. I converted the year, month and day to datetime but I got a different result.

Comment: Do not include data/code/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question and added a link to the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary issue is that your `groupby` doesn't reflect the grouping shown in the desired plot.  Including the `'year'` column means you keep separate dates from different years.  But the plot looks like it is trying to show what an average year looks like; i.e. *dates from different years should be binned together.*

So I would instead try just grouping by month and day:

```
dailyMean = df.groupby(['month','day'])['births'].mean().reset_index()

#    month  day    births
# 0      1  1.0  4009.225
# 1      1  2.0  4247.400
# 2      1  3.0  4500.900
# 3      1  4.0  4571.350
# 4      1  5.0  4603.625
```

And then (I would agree with others that) converting to timestamps might be the most flexible for plotting.  You could make timestamps out of your data using an arbitrary year (I choose `2000` as it is a leap year):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=2000, month=dailyMean['month'], day=dailyMean['day']))
```

Then you can just plot the births against the dates, and use `matplotlib.dates` to do a little additional formatting:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, dailyMean['births'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.set_xlim(dates.iloc[0], dates.iloc[-1])
```

[image]

Note that this looks a little different from your expected graph; I think the major thing is that mine includes February 29th and it looks like yours doesn't.  It looked like your data came [from here](https://www.kaggle.com/asauve/cdc-us-births-data-19692008).  I had to do some cleaning, and maybe you have done different.  But here's my full example:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# load the data from https://www.kaggle.com/asauve/cdc-us-births-data-19692008
df = pd.read_csv('births.csv')


# get what each day of the year looks like on average
dailyMean = df.groupby(['month','day'])['births'].mean().reset_index()

# clean data by removing rows that aren't real dates
dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020', '12-31-2020', freq='D')
realdates = pd.Series(tuple(zip(dr.month, dr.day)))
dfdates = pd.Series(tuple(zip(dailyMean['month'], dailyMean['day'].astype(int))))
dailyMean = dailyMean[dfdates.isin(realdates)]

# make a new dates series for plotting
dates = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=2000, month=dailyMean['month'], day=dailyMean['day']))

# plot
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, dailyMean['births'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.set_xlim(dates.iloc[0], dates.iloc[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @tom
I have got the lead. Actually, I did try to groupby month and day.
I think my problem was that I did not know how to plot the data.

The last two code blocks from your solution did the work.

Thank you so much once again for helping me understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want I just tried on some random manual data.
Try Using Pandas Plot

```
df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['births'].mean().plot(kind='line')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help but this is not something I wanted. Appreciate your help :)