# Get end_time by adding start_time and execution time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns start_time and execution time, I need to use these two columns and create a new column end_time, which is the sum of my start_time and execution_time:

```
        start_time        execution_time   end_time
   0    13-05-2013 04:04    00:24:48       13-05-2013 4:28:48
   1    13-05-2013 04:44    00:09:23       13-05-2013 4:53:23
   2    13-05-2013 23:24    00:06:51       13-05-2013 23:30:51
   3    22-05-2013 16:31    00:06:05       22-05-2013 16:37:05
   4    22-05-2013 20:55    00:06:51       22-05-2013 21:01:51
```

One catch here is if the minute crosses 60 it should be appended to next hour as shown in the last record. and also if the hour crosses 24 it should be appended to the next day.

Please help me in getting the results. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `df['end_time']= pd.to_datetime(df.start_time) + pd.to_timedelta(df.execution_time.astype(str))`

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651619/2901002)

Comment: I Tried this but i am getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' and the error is at pd.to_timedelta(df.execution_time.astype(str))

Comment: Can you try `df['end_time']= pd.to_datetime(df.start_time) + pd.to_timedelta(df.execution_time.astype(str), errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))` ?

Comment: Yes This worked. Thanks much @jezrael. But why was i getting the ValueError earlier? Doeas that mean i had Nan's?

Comment: Added explaantion to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some empty strings or some another bad values in `Time` column, so is necessary add `errors='coerce'` to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for missing values `NaT` for this values and replace them by `00:00:00` timedelta for avoid missing values in `end_time` if add `start_time` converted to datetimes:

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(df.execution_time.astype(str), errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
df['end_time']= pd.to_datetime(df.start_time) + td
```