# Pandas combine date column and hour column in %Y%m%d %H:%M:%S format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have an xlsx file with hourly precipitation and it has three columns: a date (form 20210727), a time ( form 01:00:00) and a precipitation value. Using pd.to_datetime I change my date column into a date:

`prec['date'] = pd.to_datetime(prec['date'], format="%Y%m%d")`

When I try to then combine the date and hour columns into a new Datetime column, I get two timestamps, the actual one (time column) and a 00:00:00 timestamp attached to my date.

`prec['Datetime'] = prec['date'].apply(str)+ ' ' + prec['hour'].apply(str)`

```
    date        hour        prec    Datetime
0   2021-07-27  00:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00 00:00:00
1   2021-07-27  01:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00 01:00:00
2   2021-07-27  02:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00 02:00:00
3   2021-07-27  03:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00 03:00:00
4   2021-07-27  04:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00 04:00:00
```

I would like to get the final Datetime without the 00:00:00 time stamp so as

```
    date        hour        prec    Datetime
0   2021-07-27  00:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 00:00:00
1   2021-07-27  01:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 01:00:00
2   2021-07-27  02:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 02:00:00
3   2021-07-27  03:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 03:00:00
4   2021-07-27  04:00:00    0.0     2021-07-27 04:00:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine Date and Time columns using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
prec['Datetime'] = prec['date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")+ ' ' + prec['hour'].apply(str)
```