# How do I parse time values that are over 23:59 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, parsing

In a csv file, there is a column with a **date (month/day/year)** and **TWO** columns with **time (hour:minute)**. One time column is the **start time** and the other column is the **end time**. All columns are objects that are not converted into datetime.
In the time columns, there are some time values that are over 23:59 and if they are over, the format is hour:minute:second (what I've seen so far). **Ex: 24:50:00, 25:35:00, etc**. How would I parse the time columns? I'm getting an error message and I think it's because the time is over the usual limit. Also, for the date column I'm told that if the start time column exceeds 23:59, the date would increase based on how much the time is over the limit. Ex: date of 1/1/2000 with start time column of 24:50:00 (hour:hour:minute) is 1/2/2000 with time 0:50 (hour:minute). Do I create a new column and merge the two, and if so, how? And what should I do for the end time column?

When reading the csv file, I tried to parse the time series with parse_dates:

```
time_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates = ['StartTime'], date_parser = time_parser)
```

But I get a error message that tells me something like:
"25:39 does not match format %H:%M".
I'm not sure if the parser just ignores the extra :00 (second) as mentioned above, but I think the problem is that the time exceeds 23:59.
How should I go about approaching this?

Comment: please provide an example of the file content (a few rows ensuring some with the time >23:59) and the matching expected output

Comment: are those valid times in some way, or do you want to *discard* those values?

Comment: Those are valid times, for values over 23:59, it just means the next day.

Comment: You cannot parse to `time` then, you'll have to use [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) and add that to the date as a duration. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651619/10197418) how this looks like in pandas.

Comment: Does timedelta automatically account for addition in this way? Like 1/1/2000 20:00 (month/day/year hour:minute) + 5:00 (hour:minute) = 1/2/2000 1:00?

Comment: yes, that is exactly why you'd use this approach.

Comment: The pd.to_timedelta() function isn't reading the time format. It says, "ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format". I think it might not be able to read anything above 23:59 either.

Comment: When testing if timedelta values auto increments day for values over 23:59, it works. But when trying to convert the time columns, it doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the extra :00 for those values? I still can't convert the time columns into timedelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the date to `datetime`, parse the time to `timedelta` and add the two together. Note that [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) expects a certain input format (HH:MM:SS), which in your case could be enforced by prepending `:00`. Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["1/1/2000", "1/1/2000", "1/1/2000"], 
                   "time": ["23:59", "24:50", "25:30"]})


df["datetime"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%Y") + 
    pd.to_timedelta(df["time"] + ":00")
    )

df
       date   time            datetime
0  1/1/2000  23:59 2000-01-01 23:59:00
1  1/1/2000  24:50 2000-01-02 00:50:00
2  1/1/2000  25:30 2000-01-02 01:30:00
```