# Merge 'Date' and 'Time' columns with specific format into 'Date_Time' column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I have a `df` with `Time` and `Date` columns in this specific format.

```
Time    Date
213919  220806
220905  220806
225351  220806
4101    220806
12037   220806
```

The format of `Time` is: `hhmmss`

The format of `Time` is a bit strange, the reading must begin from the end and in order to complete the `6` digits, `0` must be added to the beginning, for example `4101` refers to `00:41:01`, whereas, `12037` refers to `01:20:37`

The format of `Date` is: `yymmdd`

I would like to add a new column to my `df`, `Date_Time` which looks like this:

```
Time    Date    Date_Time    
213919  220806  06/08/2022 21:39:19
220905  220806  06/08/2022 22:09:05
225351  220806  06/08/2022 22:53:51
4101    220806  06/08/2022 00:41:01
12037   220806  06/08/2022 01:20:37
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine Date and Time columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-pandas)

Comment: How do you load your data?

Comment: @rpanai. I don't agree with you. The answer can't solve the problem. Check the mozway's answer, you have to pad Time column with leading 0.

Comment: @Corralien Padding and format can easily added to the suggested solution.

Comment: @Corralien, I don't load the data, it arrives in this format from the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two columns as string with help of [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), then pass to [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with your custom format:

```
df['Date_Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str)
                                  +df['Time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6),
                                  format='%y%m%d%H%M%S')
                     .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
                  )
```

Output:

```
     Time    Date            Date_Time
0  213919  220806  06/08/2022 21:39:19
1  220905  220806  06/08/2022 22:09:05
2  225351  220806  06/08/2022 22:53:51
3    4101  220806  06/08/2022 00:41:01
4   12037  220806  06/08/2022 01:20:37
```

Answer (score 1):

If you load your data from a csv file or an excel file, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
print(df)

# Output
            Date_Time
0 2006-08-22 21:39:19
1 2006-08-22 22:09:05
2 2006-08-22 22:53:51
3 2006-08-22 00:41:01
4 2006-08-22 01:20:37
```

If you don't use `parse_dates` parameter, you will have:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)

# Output
     Time    Date
0  213919  220806
1  220905  220806
2  225351  220806
3    4101  220806
4   12037  220806
```

Input data file:

```
Time,Date
213919,220806
220905,220806
225351,220806
004101,220806
012037,220806
```

**Update**

> The numbers are not padded in the original csv

```
def pad_time(x):
    return x.zfill(6)
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']], converters={'Time': pad_time})
print(df)

# Output
            Date_Time
0 2006-08-22 21:39:19
1 2006-08-22 22:09:05
2 2006-08-22 22:53:51
3 2006-08-22 00:41:01
4 2006-08-22 01:20:37
```

Comment: The numbers are not padded in the original csv

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I updated my answer according your comment.