# Prevent change in date after conversion from string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

After converting the time column from 'object' to 'datetime' dtype, I noticed some dates are altered.

**Initial dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
order_details_id  order_id order_date   order_time  item_id
0                     1         1     1/1/23  11:38:36 AM    109.0
1                     2         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    108.0
2                     3         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    124.0
3                     4         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    117.0
4                     5         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    129.0
```

**Conversion**

```
df['order_date] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date])
print(df)
order_details_id  order_id  order_date   order_time    item_id
0                     1         1  2023-01-01    11:38:36 AM      109
1                     2         2  2023-01-01    11:57:40 AM      108
2                     3         2  2023-01-01    11:57:40 AM      124
3                     4         2  2023-01-01    11:57:40 AM      117
4                     5         2  2023-01-01    11:57:40 AM      129
   

df['order_time] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_time])
print(df)
order_details_id  order_id  order_date          order_time     item_id
0                     1         1  2023-01-01   2023-12-29 11:38:36      109
1                     2         2  2023-01-01   2023-12-29 11:57:40      108
2                     3         2  2023-01-01   2023-12-29 11:57:40      124
3                     4         2  2023-01-01   2023-12-29 11:57:40      117
4                     5         2  2023-01-01   2023-12-29 11:57:40      129
```

I understand that in `datetime` `format=%y/%m/%d` is mandatory.
The problem lies in the `order_time` column: notice the change in date from `2023-01-01` to `2023-12-29`.

Comment: What do you mean with "*I understand that in datetime format=%y/%m/%d is mandatory.*"?

Comment: After conversion from object to datetime column, it became an actual date and time column

Comment: Now this looks like exactly what you need: [Combine Date and Time columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17978092/12846804). Please check it out.  *Likely a duplicate*

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should find everything in there. In your own time, please send feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect the time-of-day column (`"order_time"`) to also carry date information. What makes you assume that? For example `"11:38:36 AM"`, as provided in your post, **does not carry date information**.

Note that when converting a time of day in absence of date information, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) falls back to *today*. This is what is happening here, so for the reader reproducing your code, it will show the day they do so. For you, `"2023-12-29"` was likely the day you ran this code before posting here.

In fact both columns in your provided input dataframe (`"order_time"` and `"order_date"`) are required to know date and time. Resolve this by either of those:

1. Assembling both columns prior to datetime conversion, as in [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19378497/12846804)

```
# Concatenate date and time with a space, then apply datetime format
df['order_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'].str.cat(df['order_time'], 
                                      sep=' '))
```

2. Or, even better, combine one datetime and one timedelta, as in this preferred solution of [Combine Date and Time columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651619/12846804)

```
df['order_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('order_date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('order_time'))
```

Both yield the same output: a column with full datetime information

```
   order_details_id  order_id order_date   order_time  item_id      order_datetime
0                 1         1     1/1/23  11:38:36 AM    109.0 2023-01-01 11:38:36
1                 2         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    108.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
2                 3         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    124.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
3                 4         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    117.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
4                 5         2     1/1/23  11:57:40 AM    129.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
```

Data types check:

```
df.dtypes

order_details_id             int64
order_id                     int64
order_date                  object
order_time                  object
item_id                    float64
order_datetime      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

Alternatively,
It is even recommended that you should read both columns `order_date` and `order_time` as a single column like this as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978188/12846804

```
   order_details_id  order_id     order_date_time  item_id
0                 1         1  1/1/23 11:38:36 AM    109.0
1                 2         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    108.0
2                 3         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    124.0
3                 4         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    117.0
4                 5         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    129.0
```

Which you can get with this generator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_details_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
                   'order_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2},
                   'order_date_time': {0: '1/1/23 11:38:36 AM',
                                       1: '1/1/23 11:57:40 AM',
                                       2: '1/1/23 11:57:40 AM',
                                       3: '1/1/23 11:57:40 AM',
                                       4: '1/1/23 11:57:40 AM'},
                   'item_id': {0: 109.0, 1: 108.0, 2: 124.0, 3: 117.0, 4: 129.0}}
```

Then your line works:

```
df['order_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date_time'])

   order_details_id  order_id     order_date_time  item_id            order_dt
0                 1         1  1/1/23 11:38:36 AM    109.0 2023-01-01 11:38:36
1                 2         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    108.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
2                 3         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    124.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
3                 4         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    117.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
4                 5         2  1/1/23 11:57:40 AM    129.0 2023-01-01 11:57:40
```