# How to include a specific date to a datetime column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a csv file that has two columns: one for date and one for time. When processing it with pandas, I do the following:

```
df= pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False, sep=";")
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y", exact=False)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%H:%M:%S", exact=False)
```

Which results in df["Time"] being this:

```
0        1900-01-01 10:01:46

1        1900-01-01 10:01:47

2        1900-01-01 10:01:48

3        1900-01-01 10:01:50

4        1900-01-01 10:01:51
```

.
.
.

That makes my plotly script x axis be the following:

[image: x axis in my plot]

How can I add the correct date to the Time column (which I have stored in my `df["Date"] column)`?

I have tried to do like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-pandas):

```
df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
```

But it didin't work and I got the following

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and
> 'str'

Comment: You can just do `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])`

Comment: I got the following: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str' "

Comment: What are correct date and times?

Comment: I have several days of data in a single csv file, to which I iterate over and Analyse day by day in my script.

Comment: If the scale on the x-axis is an issue, the way to do this is to set the scale reference to seconds. Try this. `fig.update_xaxes(dtick="1000*60")` There are more details in the [references](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels).

Comment: @pedlobs after you read data from csv, and before you convert them with `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

We need a minimal and reproducible example to answer.
Let's create a brief one.

```
import io
import pandas

csv1 = '''Date;Time
2022-05-01;10:01:46
2022-05-02;10:01:47
2022-05-03;10:01:48
2022-05-04;10:01:50
2022-05-05;10:01:51
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv1), sep=';')
```

df

```
         Date      Time
0  2022-05-01  10:01:46
1  2022-05-02  10:01:47
2  2022-05-03  10:01:48
3  2022-05-04  10:01:50
4  2022-05-05  10:01:51
```

**Code**

Based on your comment, the `Date` column is assumed to be `datetime` and the `Time` column is assumed to be `str`. However, this is not certain, so let's change the Date column back to datetime and the Time column to Timedelta and merge them.

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

out:

```
0   2022-05-01 10:01:46
1   2022-05-02 10:01:47
2   2022-05-03 10:01:48
3   2022-05-04 10:01:50
4   2022-05-05 10:01:51
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False, sep=";")

# Convert "Date" and "Time" columns to datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y", exact=False)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%H:%M:%S", exact=False)

# Combine "Date" and "Time" into a new datetime column
df["Datetime"] = df["Date"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

# Now, df["Datetime"] will contain the combined datetime values
```